# Tomcat root directory/working folder for webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, path, working-directory

Hi I have some strange problem. I migrate from embedded tomcat to standalone and when application is searching for folder with configuration the root directory is tomcat/bin folder. For example when I want load configuration file form directory in webapp/myApp/web-inf/conf application search it in tomcat/bin/conf. How I can change this behavior of application? I see this depends on where the Tomcat server was started from.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat has two main folders `CATALINA_HOME` and `CATALINA_BASE`.

In a standard installation, they point to the same folder:

```
tomcat/
    bin/
    conf/
    lib/
    logs/
    src/
    temp/
    webapps/
    work/
```

`CATALINA_HOME` is used to find the *code* of Tomcat, i.e. the `bin` and `lib` folders.

`CATALINA_BASE` is used to find the *configuration* of Tomcat, i.e. the `conf`, `logs`, `temp`, `webapps`, and `work` folder, although only the `conf` folder is necessarily there, as the others can be located elsewhere by the `conf/server.xml` and `conf/logging.properties` files.

You webapp goes in the `webapps` folder. The content of the `conf` folder (in your `WEB-INF`) must be moved to the `conf` folder.

---

Or you can leave the `conf` folder where it is and set `CATALINA_HOME` to where Tomcat is installed, and `CATALINA_BASE` to the `WEB-INF` folder, i.e. the folder that contains the `conf` folder.